# Writing regression results in latex

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

I'm trying to write a regression results in Latex as follows:

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y_t = &\varphi_1rer_t+\varphi_2 \pi_t + u_t \\
t: &[2.89] [8.63] \\
\sigma : &[2.5] [0,69]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

as can be seen in the pdf-viewer, it only does one alignment for the first square bracket.
But , what I want is in the following picture.
[image]

I want each square bracket to align under the correspondent coefficients.
Which command should I use to produce what i want .Please give an example of your suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, provide code of your example (what you try so far) instead of its image. And code let be complete, with start `\documnetclass{...}`  and ends with `\end{document}`.  By the way, searching of SE will gives to you a lot of similar questions with helpful answers.

Comment: `alignat` might be helpful...

Comment: I'm curious: You seem to be reporting the t-stats and the standard errors but not the point estimates of the coefficients. Are the point estimates reported elsewhere? Or, is the reader supposed to calculate them by him/herself based on the values of the t-stats and standard errors?

Comment: Mico, this is just for example. I'm gonna report of course the point estimates too .Thank you for being careful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using the AMS-provided `alignat` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
    y_t = {}      & \varphi_1rer_t & {}+{} & \varphi_2 \pi_t & {} + u_t \\
    t: \quad      & [2.89]         &       & [8.63]          &  \\
    \sigma: \quad & [2.5]          &       & [0.69]          &  \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

I've lined up the columns to make it more obvious.  The `{}` pairs help to correct the spacing.  The `\quad` similarly.

[image]

See [the AMS documentation](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/?lang=en) for details.  In particular `amsldoc.pdf`.

Comment: There's a bit too much space before the second `+`. One workaround for that could be `\mathrlap` (see my answer) on the numbers in the rows below.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. or you could just leave the 5th column out and put the `+ u_t` in the 4th (since they are all left aligned).

Comment: @Thruston Ah yes, that was much easier.

Answer (score 0):

A way via some `\hphantom`s and `\mathrlap`. The latter is defined by `mathtools`, hence I've replaced `amsmath` with that package. (`mathtools` loads and extends `amsmath`.) Note that in `align` you should have `&=`, not `=&`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y_t &= \varphi_1rer_t+\varphi_2 \pi_t + u_t \\
t: & \hphantom{{}={}} \mathrlap{[2.89]}\hphantom{\varphi_1rer_t+{}} [8.63] \\
\sigma:  &\hphantom{{}={}}\mathrlap{[2.5]}\hphantom{\varphi_1rer_t+{}} [0.69]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]